# How to open a HTML file within JFrame?

Tags: java, html, swing, jframe, integration

I'm developing a Google map application in Java Swing using the NetBeans framework. I wrote the following code:

```
private void open_site() {
    BrowserUtil.setVersion(Version.V6_22);

    browser = new Browser();
    view = new BrowserView(browser);

    map_panel.add(view, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    browser.addTitleListener((TitleEvent evt) -> {
        jLabel1.setText("   " + evt.getTitle());
    });

    browser.addConsoleListener((ConsoleEvent evt) -> {
        System.out.println("LOG: " + evt.getMessage());
    });

    browser.addLoadListener(new LoadAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onFinishLoadingFrame(FinishLoadingEvent evt) {
            evt.getBrowser().setZoomLevel(-2);
        }
    });

    browser.loadURL("C:\\HTMLGMaps\\simple_map.html");
}
```

I called this function within the constructor.
But my java code is showing the Error as:

```
01:02:23 SEVERE: Failed to extract Chromium binaries into 
    C:\Users\Muhammad Afzaal\AppData\Local\JxBrowser\browsercore-69.0.3497.12.6.23.1 
    com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ChromiumExtractorException:
    The /chromium-win32.7z resource cannot be found in JAR files
```